# Using fix point iteration method?

Tags: numerical-methods, education, applications, fixed-point-iteration

> Question: $x\sin x=50$ the root lie between the interval [51,52]

consider,
$$x\sin x=50$$
$$x=\arcsin (50/x)=g(x)$$
now, we check $|g'(x)|<1 $
since, 
$\arcsin (50/x)=g(x)$
$$g'(x)=1/[1-(50/x)^2]^{1/2} (-50/x^2)\\
|g'(x)|=|50/[x(x^2-2500)^{1/2}]|$$
let here $x=52$
$$|g'(x)|=|50/[52(2704-2500)^{1/2}]|\\
|g'(x)|=0.0673<1$$
now we by fix point iteration method,
$$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$$
let $x_{o}=51.5$
$$x_1=\arcsin (50/x_{o})=1.1.3288$$
the value of my $x_{1}$ does not lie in interval $[51,52]$
please help me to point out my mistake in the solution.

Comment: Please use markup to make your question legible. And line breaks and such.

Comment: Is the question in degrees or radians?

Answer (score 0):

The main branch of $\arcsin$ has values between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$. To get to any other branch you have to shift by multiples of $\pi$ and every other interval has to be mirrored.

Since $51.5/\pi=16.39295913846522$ and
$$
[15.5\pi,16.5\pi] \simeq [48.69468613064179,\,51.83627878423159]
$$
covers most of the given interval,
the fixed point formula that likely will produce a solution is
$$
g(x)=16\pi+\arcsin(50/x).
$$

---

short test in python

```
In [12]: x=51.5;
In [13]: for k in range(15): x=16*pi+asin(50/x); print "%.20f" % x

51.59433370146560804415
51.58703269445761208090
51.58758931983782503039
51.58754683447086364367
51.58755007695501859644
51.58754982948691036881
51.58754984837379709006
51.58754984693234035831
51.58754984704235369009
51.58754984703395507495
51.58754984703459456341
51.58754984703455193085
51.58754984703455193085
51.58754984703455193085
51.58754984703455193085
```

Comment: what are the steps involved in getting this value of g(x)

Comment: You need to identify in which period of the sine the interval `[51,52]` falls. Then correct the inverse function for one of the monotonous segments there.